# WebGL Multi-Render Target: For drawBuffers, what does gl.BACK do?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I am working on my Multiple Render Target pipeline and I came across a curiosity in the docs that I don't fully understand and googling for an hour hasn't helped me find a clear answer.

You utilize `gl.drawBuffers([...])` to link the locations used in your shader to actual color attachments in your framebuffer. So, most of the expected parameters makes sense:

gl.NONE - Make the shader output for this location NOT output to any Color attachment in the FBO

gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT[0 - 15] - Make the shader location output to the specified color attachment.

But then we have this mysterious target (from the docs):

`gl.BACK: Fragment shader output is written into the back color buffer.`

I don't think I understand what the back color buffer is, especially relative to the currently attached FBO. As far as I know you don't specify a 'back color buffer' when making a FBO...so what does this mean? What is this 'back color buffer'?

Comment: The backbuffer is being flipped to the screen in the next frame(see [double buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics)) So it's essentially "the screen".

Comment: So you're saying every color attachment for an FBO in webgl is automagically double buffered?

Comment: Framebuffers are not double buffered, the implicit "screen buffer"(the one backing the canvas) is however. I've deleted my previous comment as it was partly incorrect as pointed out by the answer. The specifics can be found in [this specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf#nameddest=section-4.2.1).

Comment: Thanks for finding that spec. I'll use that link path to find those better detailed docs rather the docs google keeps pulling up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WebGL the backbuffer is effectively "the canvas". It's called the `backbuffer` because sometimes there is a frontbuffer. Canvas's in WebGL are double buffered. One buffer is whatever is visible, the other is the buffer you're currently drawing to.

You can't use `[gl.BACK, gl_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0]`

When writing to a framebuffer each entry can only be the same attachment or `NONE`. For example imagine you have 4 attachments. Then the array you pass to `drawBuffers` is as follows

```
gl.drawBuffers([
   gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, // OR gl.NONE,
   gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, // OR gl.NONE,
   gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, // OR gl.NONE,
   gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, // OR gl.NONE,
])
```

You can not swap around attachments.

```
gl.drawBuffers([
   gl.NONE,
   gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, // !! ERROR! This has to be COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 or NONE
])
```

You can't use `gl.BACK`  `gl.BACK` is only for when writing to the canvas, in other words then the frame buffer is set to `null` as in `gl.bindFramebuffer(null);`

```
gl.drawBuffers([
  gl.BACK, // OR gl.NONE
]);
```

note: drawBuffers state is part of the state of each framebuffer (and canvas).  See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/kcjxu7y0/) and [this](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html?exampleId=draw-cube-on-cube)

Comment: You are absolutely right, do you know of any real-world(ish) use cases for configuring the default framebuffer using `NONE` and `BACK` ?

Comment: I can see use for `NONE` say in the case you have procedurally generated shaders that will output to a given render target. The FBO may have 4 attachments but the shader only has 2 outputs...so you can generate the shader to properly align with the FBO and use NONE to indicate outputs the shader will not be rendering to, which should prevent undefined outputs.